# prevent multiple creation with xml calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, server, mutex

In my application which is spread among a number of servers, need to create an id by calling an external service. I can use lock but it will only be server specific. I want it to be safe across application, i.e. all servers. If a create call comes in from server , lock and create and then let other servers pick up the created one ? Was thinking about MUTEX. Good idea?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this not to be a throttle on performance, you could copy the MS SQL Server method (used in replicated servers on sequence number columns). In this case you assign a block of values to each server, unique to that server, which it consumes. The block of IDs comes from a core single server.

Consuming servers only need to make a blocking call to the core server when it runs out (or projects that it will run out) of IDs to consume.

This is highly scalable and guarantees uniqueness but it does not guarantee contiguous sequences during processing, but eventually all records laid down in historical storage will be contiguous as each server will eventually serve up all its IDs.

Heres a reference to how SQL Server achieves this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/replicate-identity-columns